# Apache wink REST - IllegalArgumentException for a particular header

Tags: web-services, apache, rest, http-headers, apache-wink

My rest service works fine if I give the authentication header. But the same is throwing 500 internal Service error when I add `log-level=debug|info` along with the authentication header. I don't know where it is failing. I'm getting only the below errors.

```
org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException
IllegalArgumentException occurred during the handlers chain invocation
```

I could not able to get more information about the error. Please help me. Thanks.

**Update:**

i'm using wink incubator 1.1.1

Comment: Full exception's stacktrace can be helpful. Also try to turn debug logging for wink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast found the solution to this. Instead of `debug`, when i try with `Debug` this is working fine. The exception was thrown from a .jar. when I got the source of it, i debugged and found the value for loglevel was in a enum and its in camelcase. The issue is fixed now. Thanks for your responses.